# Detecting System/Browser shutdown event in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on client/server application where I need to detect unexpected shutdown from client side. Basically what I need to do is that if the client browser's window shuts down unexpectedly due to power loss or user closes the browser, an ajax call is made to the server with some data.. Any idea how can I achieve something like this.?

Comment: Can't be guaranteed. All you have to work with is the `window.unbeforeunload` event. That is to say unless you're working with a real time application using `NodeJS` and something like `Socket.io`, where you could assume that a disconnection from the socket means that the client has terminated the session.

Comment: It is a real time application but I am working in Laravel. Any idea or suggestion to make it work in Laravel.?

Comment: Maybe use `ignore_user_abort` read http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: I would also go with the websocket integration. Laravel 5.3 ships with some of this integration with Laravel echo, check it out here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting

Comment: You can look at pusher. Create a channel for each user and then your server will be notified when the user goes offline (channel_vacated) https://pusher.com/docs/webhooks#channel-existence

Comment: thank you everyone for your time. @El_Matella thank you for pointing me out towards broadcasting..will surely look into that..